# What do I need to do to make a different replacement LCD work on my Latitude e6430?

Tags: display, lcd, dell-latitude

I have a working Dell Latitude e6430 with a smashed screen, and I also have three incomplete e6420s which all have their screens. If at all possible, I want to use one of my spare screens to replace the broken one.

The broken screen is an AUO B140XW01. Two of the other screens are Samsung LTN140KT04s, and I also have an AUO B140RW03.

I first tried swapping out just the LCD module, but the colours and resolution were way off. I read somewhere that different screens need different cables, but the cables weren't the same and the indicator lights module didn't fit in the other screen case.

Next I tried swapping out the entire top half of the laptop, replacing it with a screen case containing one of the LTN140KT04s. This actually worked, the resolution and colours were fine. However, the battery light constantly showed a light orange (not nearly as bright as the when flashing to indicate low battery). That doesn't appear on the list of indications given in the manual. I'm scared that I could damage my battery. With the old screen in, the battery indicator behaves normally.

I have had a hard time trying to find out which screens are compatible with what, and also what more than the LCD screen itself needs to change. What do I need to do to make one of my spare screens work with my Latitude e6430?

Comment: I do have pictures of the labels on the back of each screen if needed.

Comment: Whatever else you find out, make sure to disconnect the battery *before* disconnecting the screen, otherwise things can go horribly wrong.

Comment: Battery out is always the first step :)

Comment: Screens needs to be a match for the video power converter in the laptop. So no you cannot "make" it work.

Comment: @Moab see now that the original screen says v.9, while one of the others says v.1. I guess that is the end of that idea.